# Stripe: Discount 1st year of a subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

Stripe says intro rates on a subscription aren't able to be done, it would require a manual process of signing the user up for a product at 1 price, and then getting them to switch over to a 2nd product at a different price. Has anyone ever been able to successfully figure out a way to do this?

Basically, what I would like to do is have a user create an reoccurring annual subscription with a base price of $100.
I'd like the first year for them to be 10% off, so $90, with an annual renewal rate of the base price, $100.

I tried solving through coupons and graduated pricing but neither seemed to work. Curious if anyone has ideas or if a 1 time, automatic discount or intro rate is something that's just not doable at all.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions/255746#255746) SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Coupons should work really, (a coupon with duration:once and e.g. percent_off:10). You'd have to share the code you used and what you saw happen versus what you expected for us to be able to help. https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/coupons